# Missing 'Model Overview' Tab in Mysql Workbench on Mac OS X

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench, workbench

I designed some schema with mysql workbench at windows, while bringing to mac it's not showing the schema objects/tables at model view but it's showing the diagram fine , updated the latest WB as well but no luck, again if i forward engineer to db it's installing without any error.

Did anyone fall this situation? Because in our team other works on windows and I'm working on MAC so if it's the problem of Windows/Mac then I will have much problem.

Please advice.

Comment: Can you add a full screen capture?  Also, to help you get started, you could possibly unzip the mwb file and look at the .xml that is generated.

Comment: I found a similar problem and managed to fix it. Check this answer: [MySQL workbench Missing management tools MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385288/mysql-workbench-mac-os-missing-management-tools-and-data-import-export)